# Woocommerce Add to Cart redirect to parent category

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I've been trying this for days, I just found this code:

```
//This is to redirect add to cart button to restaurant page add_filter
('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_previousCat');
function redirect_to_previousCat( $url ) {if ( isset( $_POST['add-to-cart'] ) )
{  
    $product_id = (int) apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $_POST['add-to-cart'] );
    $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        $product_cat_slug = $term->slug;      
        break; 
    }    

    if( $product_cat_slug ){
        $url = user_trailingslashit(get_permalink() . '/restaurant/' . $product_cat_slug );    
    }  
    }
return $url;
}
```

my goal was to redirect the add to cart button to its

> /restaurant/parent-category-slug

but what the code does was redirect it to the /restaurant/product-category/

I really need some help here.

Comment: Please format your code properly. It's unreadable...

Comment: sorry.. I'm not a programmer and I only scavenging codes.. I think someone format my code yesterday.. hope you can help me..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the [`get_term_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) function.

Therefore, you'd modify your code to this:

```
if( $product_cat_slug ){
   $url = get_term_link( $product_cat_slug, 'product_cat' );    
}
```

Comment: Thanks @helgatheviking but I think its not what I'm trying to achieve. What I want to do is get the Parent Category Slug from the product that I added. then insert the slug to a link:


home/restaurant/parent-category-slug/


then use it to redirect to that page. the reason for that is because I made parent category slug identical to restaurant page permalink.

home/category/sample-restaurant-name/
home/restaurant/sample-restaurant-name/

because I can't insert contents to the categories.

Comment: Well I'm confused. Is restaurant not a taxonomy? Do you have hierarchical categories and aren't getting the top level?